# Microsoft Word macro to copy text and past it in find and replacement

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to paste the copied text in `.Replacement.Text`. I tried this with Selection Paste, but this doesn't work.

To be clear: I'm trying to copy text in a Microsoft Word document and I want the copied text changed into multiply fieldcodes <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. So my Word document will change all field codes at once.

```
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=5, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = Not ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "00000"
        .Replacement.Text ="Selection.Paste"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = Not ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Fields.Update
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no direct clipboard support available in VBA. You can use the clipboard using Windows API functionality though (a simple Google search and you will find a code sample how to do it). However, before investing into that option: Would be working with the currently selected text be a suitable option for your? It's much simpler to access the current selection (just use `.Replacement.Text = Selection.Text`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to use `Selection.WholeStory`

```
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=5, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = Not ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes
'        Selection.WholeStory
    searchText=selection.text
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "00000"
            .Replacement.Text =searchText
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindAsk
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = Not ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes
        Selection.WholeStory
        Selection.Fields.Update
    End Sub
```